# A novel about Ragnarok as narrated by Hoenir

Tags: story-identification, norse-gods, ragnarok

I liked a novel that I read about 10 years ago. It was new then and I got it from the public library. I've forgotten the name of it and the author.

I've done a lot of frustrated googling, which turns up the Marvel Universe and Magic the Gathering, etc. It is the story of Ragnarok as told first-person by Hoenir, the god who has been forgotten or ignored. The tone of it is light and somewhat sarcastic, IIRC, because everyone already knows what will happen to them, which makes the whole exercise pointless:

Thor kills the Midgard Serpent but is smothered in its venom; Odin is eaten by the Fenris Wolf; Vidar uses his supernatural leather shoe, made from countless scraps of leather to stand on the lower jaw of the Fenris Wolf and tear his jaws apart; etc. etc. It’s all according to the mythical plan. This is retold in a few pages.

Hoenir doesn't know what his role is. Most of the book is his story leading up to Ragnarok, and his frustration that everyone is following their inescapable fate, and his confusion because he doesn't know what he is supposed to do. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C5%93nir) claims that "Also according to Völuspá, Hœnir was one of the few gods that would survive Ragnarök."

After Ragnarok, Hoenir goes through some kind of portal and ends up on a beach (I think), with a sword that he got from Vili (?) and a girlfriend, I think. He is ready to start all over again and try to do better than the gods did before.

If you can identify this book, please do.

Comment: Was there anything that would make this book something other than a retelling of Ragnarok from Hoenir's perspective? Did the novel contain anything [_about the Norse Pantheon in relation to a science fictional setting_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11302)? This might be better suited over at [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) if not

Comment: Yes, there was quite a bit of story leading up to the event of Ragnarok, all of which was also from Hoenir's point of view. As I recall, he visited the warriors in Valhalla, for one thing, and told them that Ragnarok was coming, and they complained that they hadn't been informed by Odin. My memory is probably faulty, but something like that happened. He also ran around Asgard, saving people from burning houses. None of that, or the other adventures of Hoenir were mythological. The Norse pantheon was fairly well covered, fictionally. I do not think this is either science fiction or literature.

Comment: Just for others searching, also posted at https://fanfiaddict.com/30norseinspiredfictionbooks/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Heh. I forgot that I had already asked there. I must have copied my question to my diary. I've been trying to remember this book for a while. I have googled, searched the public library website...  My memory may indeed be failing. I might be getting old, but it's better than the alternative!